# Column-wise sum of a 3D tensor in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am trying to perform a column-wise sum operation on an Eigen tensor. In Matlab, the operations look as follows.

```
// 2D array
A = [1 2 3; 1 2 3; 1 2 3]

// Making the 2D array a 3D array by adding another array to the third dimension

A(:,:,2) = [1 2 3; 1 2 3; 1 2 3]

A = 
// First slice
A(:,:,1) = 1 2 3
           1 2 3
           1 2 3
 
// Second slice
A(:,:,2) = 1 2 3
           1 2 3
           1 2 3 

// Sum along dim 1 
S = sum(A,1)

S= 
// slice 1 summed along the columns
S(:,:,1) = 
            3 6 9

//slice 2 summed along the columns
S(:,:,2) = 
            3 6 9
```

This is what I tried in Eigen

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
using Eigen::Tensor;
using namespace Eigen;
using MccTensor2D = Eigen::Tensor<Eigen::scomplex, 2>;
using MccTensor3D = Eigen::Tensor<Eigen::scomplex, 3>;
int main()
{

 MccTensor3D testTensor(2,2,2);
 testTensor.setRandom();
 auto testTensorOp  = testTensor.sum(0); //Error here
}
```

The error is shown below. Thank you for your help in advance.

/usr/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorReduction.h: In instantiation of ‘const int Eigen::internal::traitsEigen::TensorReductionOp<Eigen::internal::SumReducer<std::complex<float >, const int, const Eigen::Tensorstd::complex<float, 3>, Eigen::MakePointer> >::NumDimensions’:
/usr/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorBase.h:36:22:   required from ‘const int Eigen::TensorBaseEigen::TensorReductionOp<Eigen::internal::SumReducer<std::complex<float >, const int, const Eigen::Tensorstd::complex<float, 3>, Eigen::MakePointer>, 0>::NumDimensions’
/usr/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorBase.h:533:5:   required from ‘class Eigen::TensorBaseEigen::TensorReductionOp<Eigen::internal::SumReducer<std::complex<float >, const int, const Eigen::Tensorstd::complex<float, 3>, Eigen::MakePointer>, 0>’
/usr/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorReduction.h:350:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::TensorReductionOpEigen::internal::SumReducer<std::complex<float >, const int, const Eigen::Tensorstd::complex<float, 3>, Eigen::MakePointer>’
egExample.cpp:737:30:   required from here
/usr/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorReduction.h:33:61: error: incomplete type ‘Eigen::internal::array_size’ used in nested name specifier
33 |   static const int NumDimensions = XprTraits::NumDimensions - array_size::value;

Answer (score 1):

The reduction operations such as `.sum(...)` take a fixed-size array as argument, with a list of dimensions along which to reduce. [See here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html#title57).
So you only need to replace `.sum(0)` with `.sum(std::array<int,1>{0})`.

Here is a full example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>

int main(){
    auto t = Eigen::Tensor<int, 3>(3,3,2);
    t.setValues({{{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}},{{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}},{{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}}});
    auto ax = std::array<int,1>{0};
    auto ts  = t.sum(ax); 
    std::cout << t << '\n';
    std::cout << ts << '\n';
}
```

[See on compiler-explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/aK39Prhjs).